# update value of object in django template

Tags: mysql, django, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to refresh a sub template block included in index.html file.

a1 , a2 , a3.. values are constantly updated in mysql database. ( every 3-5 seconds)

reloading a `<div>` with javascript did not work for this task because the replaced values are the same as old values in `<html>` source

```
<div id="replace_me">
    <ul>
        <li>total: 109000</li>
        <li>a1: 58055</li>
        <li>a2: 34820</li>
        <li>a3: 16116</li>
        <li>a4: 9</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is a summary of what I've done so far

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Output(Real-Time)</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        setInterval(updateStats, 2000)
    });
    function updateStats{
        $('#replace_me').load('/');
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Parsing..</h1>
{% block mytext %}
Dynamic part (will be replaced constantly)
{% endblock%}
</body>
</html>
```

**ref_ajax.html**

```
{% if pStats %}
<div id="replace_me">
<div>
    <ul>
    {% for p in pStats %}
        <li>Total: {{ p.total }}</li>
        <li>a1 : {{ p.a1 }}</li>
        <li>a2 : {{ p.a2 }}</li>
        <li>a3 : {{ p.a3 }}</li>
        <li>a4 : {{ p.a4 }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
{% else %}
    <p>Data not available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

**ref.html**

```
{% extends "pcount/index.html" %}
{% block mytext %}
{% include "pcount/ref_ajax.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render , render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from pcount.models import Cpt

def index(request):
    pStats = Cpt.objects.all()
    context = {'pStats' : pStats}
    if request.is_ajax():
        tmp = "pcount/ref_ajax.html"
    else:
        tmp = "pcount/ref.html"
    return render_to_response(tmp, {'pStats' : pStats}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Any suggestions on getting the latest values from the mysql db with auto-refresh?

Thank You

**edit0:**

in browser:

output1

[image: output1]

output2

[image: output2]

Output2 cannot be observed unless I hit refresh manually.
Only the counters need to be refreshed every 2-3 seconds to get a real-time monitoring effect. Header should not be refreshed.

**edit1:**

to clarify the question:

[image: content_overview]

The question is about how to do changes in dynamic regions without reloading the static regions, so that page does not completely refresh.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: hi, i am not getting the latest values from the database. a1,a2 values are changing every 2-3 seconds(in db, by another application) but the change is not observed in html unless i refresh manually in browser. and `<meta> http-equiv="refresh"...` does not provide a seamless refresh

Comment: Is the Ajax executing? Is the URL being called, and is it returning data? What, exactly, is happening?

Comment: Daniel, Ajax is executing and the values are correct. I have edited the question and included screenshot of the output.

Comment: That didn't answer the question. If the Ajax is executing and the returned values are correct, then what **exactly** is the problem? I can't understand what you're trying to ask.

Comment: code works. there is no problem.But it must be changed so that header or any other static parts are not refreshed. I only want to reload sub-template that is included in index.html

Comment: Even though it refreshes the ref_ajax.html , output values does not change after each interval (btw they change in the mysql database).

Comment: Is your update function running within a transaction, by any chance? Have you tried committing it at regular intervals?